# Incomplete circuit diagrams: how to draw equivalent circuit diagrams?

Tags: circuit-analysis, reference-materials

Generally what I see in textbook problems is a diagram like this:

[image]

These contain open terminals all over (like the V_CC terminal and the capacitor terminal in this particular case) which makes it impossible to apply KVL and KCL.

Is there any general method to draw the so called "equivalent circuit diagram" which doesn't have open ends and can be actually solved? I couldn't find a reference in any book that I have.

Comment: The open terminals represent points where you are supposed to connect something. This is not a complete circuit, only part of a circuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assume that the terminals are connected to something. Typically you use an ideal 'something'.

In this case,  you would assume that Vcc is connected to a voltage source between the Vcc terminal and ground, and typically you'd assume that the voltage source has zero source impedance. We use "Vcc" or similar markers (notably the ground symbol) because it gets very messy to show wires everywhere. Vcc, Vdd usually are connected to a positive voltage wrt ground while Vss, Vee are typically negative wrt ground.

The terminal on the left is for input and it might be connected to an ideal sine wave voltage source, for example. Ideal means the source impedance is zero. Because of the capacitor you can ignore it for bias point analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a battery and an input signal source: -

[image]